# Laravel if/else syntax

Tags: php, css, laravel

How do i set different states of the icon? I want it to change between a liked/not liked icon. Can i do that? I don't completely understand the syntax. The btn-success class is for the liked icon, and btn-danger is for the unliked button.

```
        @if(Auth::check())
        @if( !$unblock )
        <span data-id="{{ $key->id }}" data-like="Like" data-like-active="Remove Like" title="@if(!empty($likeUser)) Remove Like @else Like @endif" class="btn btn-xs pull-left @if(!empty($likeUser)) btn-success @else btn-danger @endif btn-like likeButton @if(!empty($likeUser)) active @endif">
            <i class="Like-icon"></i>
        </span>
        @else
```

Answer (score 2):

You're almost right just complete the condition after `@else`

[Here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#control-structures) is the place to learn more about blades and templates

It is as simple like regular PHP `if..else` condition

```
@if (Auth::check())
Authorized
@else
Nope
@endif
```

If you want to have additional conditions inside then

```
@if (Auth::check())
Authorized
//your additional conditions for authorized users
@else
Nope
@endif
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@if (count($records) === 1)
  I have one record!
@elseif (count($records) > 1)
  I have multiple records!
@else
  I don't have any records!
@endif
```

Comment: Mind to [explain your solution](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) a bit?